# finding rational complex numbers in a disk with least denominators

Tags: complex-analysis, diophantine-approximation

Suppose that I have  a disk of radius $r$ around some complex $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$:

How would one find a complex number $g$ in that disk besides $\alpha$  such that $\mathrm{Re}(g)\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathrm{Im}(g)\in\mathbb{Q}$ and the denominators of $\mathrm{Re}(g)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(g)$ are the smallest possible?

Comment: Do you have a specific case that you’re working with, or do you want a general method? If it’s the former, I’d try writing the first few convergents to the continued fraction expansion of $\Re(\alpha)$ and $\Im(\alpha)$, and seeing which pair of numbers lands you in your disk. I’m a complete outsider to this kind of thing, though, and probably lots of others will tell you more.

Comment: @Lubin: I want a general method. The motivation is that I want to find some sequence of rational complex numbers that converges to one of the nontrivial roots of $\zeta(s)$, and most root finding algorithms give a sequence of convergents that I want to perturb a bit. Since there are a lot of root finding algorithms out there, I'd prefer a general method. Once I have such a sequence, I can make telescoping series and products from it

Comment: This is not really complex analysis: the question involves the structure of $\mathbb R^2$ only, not of $\mathbb C$. ... Since the outcome will depend on $r$ in an unpredictable way, I think that a method will be an algorithm. The simplest algorithm is to compute $n\alpha \mod \mathbb Z+i\mathbb Z$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ until you reach a number with modulus less than (or equal to?) $r$.

Answer (score 2):

If we have integers $a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s$ with $ad-bc=ps-qr=-1$, then any rational complex in the rectangle with diagonal vertices $\frac ab+i\frac pq$ and $\frac cd+i\frac rs$ has denominators $\ge b+d$ (real part) and $\ge q+s$ (imaginary part). Youcould start with an integer lattice rectangle around $\alpha$ (i.e. $b=d=q=s=1$, $a=\lfloor \Re\alpha\rfloor$, $p=\lfloor \Im\alpha\rfloor$, $c=a+1$, $r=p+1$.
Then repeatedly split the rectangle along Farey sums, i.e take $\frac{a+c}{b+1}$ or $\frac{p+r}{q+s}$ (whichever has the smaller denominator), split the rectangle along the corresponding (horizontal or vertical) line and continue with the one containing $\alpha$ until one of the vertices is inside the circle. This gives you the *only* (or possibly only two) rational complex in that circle with such small denominator, except that possibly the next step gives you equally small denominators in the other coordinate.